# Is there a WFS for OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, wfs

Is there a WFS for OSM data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

im pretty sure the [answer is no.](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=7384)
However, you could serve it up [urself](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Versioning+WFS+-+OpenStreetMap)?

Comment: Thanks Simon. I saw this discussion on the OSM forum. My problem is that I have no server.

Answer (score 3):

The Carbon project might of interest.

*"this viewer can access an array of geospatial sources such as the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Web Mapping Service (WMS), Web Map Tile Service (WMTS), Web Coverage Service (WCS), **Web Feature Service (WFS)**, and Filter Encoding (FE), services such as Microsoft Bing Maps, Yahoo! Maps and **OpenStreetMap (OSM)**, as well as file formats such as ESRI Shapefiles, Google Earth KML/KMZ, DXF, MIF, Geography Markup Language (GML) and GML Simple Features (GMLsf)"*

http://www.thecarbonproject.com/gaia.php

It was used to Map Haiti via WFS and using/consuming OSM data

http://carboncloud.blogspot.com/2010/01/openstreetmap-deployed-as-wfs-for-haiti.html

Comment: Sorry, I did not find any WFS URL this website.